# Trying to make DM logger. When I send attachments, they don't want to send

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make a DM logger for my bot. When I DM the bot with an attachment, the attachment doesn't get sent and it errors with

> (node:1009) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot
> send an empty message.

The regular message embed with the content works. [Message Embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yn5D.png)                             [The DM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5MCs.png)

```
    if(message.author.id === '755781017889144903') {return;}
    getmember(client,message.author.id).then(member =>{
    console.log('Author: ' + member.username + '. Message: ' + message.content)
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.find(g => g.name === 'Bot Testing Server')
    var channel
    if(guild){
      channel = guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === "user-dm-logs")
    }
    if(channel){
      if(message.attachments.size > 0){
        console.log('attach')
        channel.send(message.attachments.url)
      
      }
      if(message.content){
        console.log('content')
     const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#FF0000")
      .setTitle("DM LOGS")
      .setDescription("New DM to <@755781017889144903>!")
      .addFields(
        { name: "User", value: `<@${member.id}>` },
        { name: "Message: ", value: `${message.content}` }
      )
      .setTimestamp();

      channel.send(exampleEmbed)
  
      
    }}
    })
    return
  }
```

Comment: We don't so "SOLVED" in the title here. If you found your solution, mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

[message.attachments](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments) is an [collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection), you need either to loop over all the collection

```js
message.attachments.forEach(att => {})
//or map your urls
message.attachments.map(att => att.url);
```

or get the first one for example

```
message.attachments.first().url
```

or if you need a specific one you can transform the collection into array and get the desired one

```
message.attachments.array()[0].url
```